# Which of the statments are true?

Tags: calculus

Which of the statments are true?

> $1.$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)+g(x))=0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow
>  a}f(x)=3$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)=-3$
>
> $2.$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$ then
>   $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(f(x)-x)=\infty$
>
> $3.$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }(f(x)-x)=\infty$ then
>   $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f(x)}{x}=\infty$

About $(1)$: i think it's true because $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)+g(x))=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)+\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x)$.

about the others i'm not sure.

Comment: I'd appreciate if anyone can help with those statements.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(x)-x=x(\dfrac{f(x)}{x}-1)$

I think you can proceeed from here for the two last questions.

Comment: i'm not sure because i'll get $\infty \cdot \infty$. and my first statement is true?

Comment: can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

For 2)

Consider: If $k(x)=\dfrac{f(x)}{x}$ then $f(x) - x = x *(k(x) - 1)$ What are the limits of $x$ and $k(x) - 1$?

For 3)

Consider $f(x) = 3x$

Comment: for 2) it will be $\infty \cdot \infty$ and for 3) i understand.